# so im using a if statement but the if statement isnt working when i get the value of maxclicks which is 50 nothing happens

Tags: lua, scripting, roblox

```lua
local MaxClicks = 50
if game.Players.LocalPlayer.leaderstats.Clicks.Value == MaxClicks then
    script.Parent.Parent.Visible = true
end
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The reason why when you get to 50 clicks you see no changes is because your if statement is only run once. If you want to check every time the `Clicks` value is changed you can use:

```lua
local MaxClicks = 50

game.Players.LocalPlayer.leaderstats.Clicks.Changed:Connect(function()
    if game.Players.LocalPlayer.leaderstats.Clicks.Value == MaxClicks then 
        script.Parent.Parent.Visible = true 
    end
end)
```

Comment: i did what you told me and nothing happend there was no error nothing at all happend?

Comment: nvm you where right i just forgot i put 50 clicks and not 25 lol